# Does UTL_HTTP have any performance issues if remote URI isn't available?

Tags: database, oracle, http, plsql, timeout

I'm using Oracle UTL_HTTP (in 11g) from a trigger to call a HTTP API, which works fine under normal circumstances.

If the remote HTTP API becomes unavailable, will the UTL_HTTP timeouts cause any performance issues for the Oracle database (i.e. does it affect any DB connections)?

For example, if my trigger would normally fire 60 times a minute, and each HTTP call completes in 25ms, this is fine. What happens if each HTTP call takes 30 seconds to timeout? After 30 seconds there would be 30 HTTP calls waiting to timeout - does Oracle keep this isolated enough or would it begin to impact on other DB users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will only affect the connection that is waiting for the UTL_HTTP.  No impact on other connections.

Did you see:  HTTP_REQUEST_TIME_OUT

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_http.htm#ARPLS70957

Comment: Thanks, I had seen that page but it doesn't make it explicitly clear whether the request timeouts impact on database performance

Comment: Expanding scope of what OP asked, is there a dedicated ThreadPool that will manage such a queue of outbound calls (in his example, 30 HTTP calls waiting to timeout)? Does it mean that 30 Core Database Process threads are going to be allocated and waiting for response timeouts?

This is to understand the possibility of impacting SLA of the other concurrently connected DB users doing transactions not connected with this flow.